# I have a [GROUP_BY_POS_AGGREGATE] error when doing aggregation on some columns having formulas

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate, databricks, aggregate-functions

I have a problem in some scala code and I cannot get over it.
I’m moving some scala project on databricks to use unity catalog, All is going well except one process I’m running.

To simplify, I have some columns that are defined as a calculation,
I have a listof Dataframes that I want to Join, calculate my columns and aggregate.

Exception:
*AnalysisException: [GROUP_BY_POS_AGGREGATE] GROUP BY 6 refers to an expression round((sum(CASE WHEN Column  OR Column ) THEN Column  ELSE 0.0D END)), 7)*

Code example:
*code is ment to be a Databricks Job on workflow
columnList contains all computed columns*

```
val dfList = groupKpiByTimeframe.map { case (timeFrame, columnList) =>
  val scopeDf = timeFrame.getDataForTimeFrame(someDf)
  positionDf
    .transform(scopeDf)
    .join(scopeDf, Seq(myColumn), leftJoin)
    .groupBy(getGroupByColumns(timeFrame, valueDate): _*)
    .agg(columnList.head, columnList.tail: _*)
dfList.reduce(_.unionByName(_, allowMissingColumns = true))
```

error is in the unionByName operation
putting a `persist() then show()` on dfs before reduce shows that all data is Ok and well evaluated. Only difference on code os that it uses  "spark_version": **"13.3.x-scala2.12"** instead of **"spark_version": "10.4.x-scala2.12" (UC requirement)**

It was all running well with previous version
I'm using **scalaVersion := "2.12.15".**